# Apache Avro with Kafka messaging and Hazelcast as persistence provider

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, apache-kafka, avro, hazelcast

from what I understand, Kafka uses message converters in order to pass messages.

For `Avro` it uses `AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter` which uses caching for optimalisation.

We are using `Hazelcast` as cache provider, thus objects need to be `Serializable`, we know why..

[image: stacktrace]

Now Avro schema is not generated as serializable and when I try to send message it fails with:

```
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema'
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:82) ~[hazelcast-3.12.9.jar:3.12.9]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:157) ~[hazelcast-3.12.9.jar:3.12.9]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:133) ~[hazelcast-3.12.9.jar:3.12.9]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:118) ~[hazelcast-3.12.9.jar:3.12.9]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.toDataWithStrategy(MapProxySupport.java:1241) ~[hazelcast-3.12.9.jar:3.12.9]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.getInternal(MapProxySupport.java:343) ~[hazelcast-3.12.9.jar:3.12.9]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:120) ~[hazelcast-3.12.9.jar:3.12.9]
    at com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCache.lookup(HazelcastCache.java:162) ~[hazelcast-spring-3.12.9.jar:3.12.9]
    at com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCache.get(HazelcastCache.java:73) ~[hazelcast-spring-3.12.9.jar:3.12.9]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.resolveSchemaForWriting(AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.java:299) ~[spring-cloud-stream-schema-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AbstractAvroMessageConverter.convertToInternal(AbstractAvroMessageConverter.java:125) ~[spring-cloud-stream-schema-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:217) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:207) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.CompositeMessageConverter.toMessage(CompositeMessageConverter.java:83) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$OutboundContentTypeConvertingInterceptor.doPreSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:263) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$AbstractContentTypeInterceptor.preSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:295) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:613) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:443) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 158 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable serializer for class org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.serializerFor(AbstractSerializationService.java:487) ~[hazelcast-3.12.9.jar:3.12.9]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:146) ~[hazelcast-3.12.9.jar:3.12.9]
    ... 174 common frames omitted
```

I have tried to configure Kafka this way from what I found:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

but it is still failing.

obviously, the question is how to overcome this? maybe I am configuring the wrong thing, but I'm not really sure how to do it properly.

EDIT:
When I add second cache manager (cafferine) into the project and mark the bean as @Primary, the cacheManager field gets set to `CaffeineCacheManager` and there is no problem with serialization. But I don't want to have two cache providers in the project and I need to explicitly set cache manager for hazelcast on cached methods..

please assist,

thank you!

Comment: Could you describe how you're using Kafka and Hazelcast together?

Comment: I can't it's transparent. nothing intentional